# problem with a header (not like the others)

Tags: header-footer

i'm a new member in the community and a general user of latex which i find really awesome, even if sometimes he drives me crazy, i have a little problem with a file i want to re-write, i know how to use the fancyhdr package etc but i found nothing with this one, i want to do a header like this:

[image]

i searched a lot on google without any results, thanks for your help

-EDIT:sorry i forgot about my code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{ulem}
\usepackage[francais]{babel}
\usepackage{url} % Pour écrire des adresses cliquables.
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{newcent} % Pour changer le pack de police.
\usepackage[top=3cm, bottom=3cm, left=4cm, right=3cm]{geometry} % Les marges.
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy} 
\renewcommand\headrulewidth{0.6pt}
\fancyhead[R]{1}




\begin{document}


fffff

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The header can be set as `tabular*`, as starting point the following example is given (notice the comments inside the file):

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[french]{babel}

% The date is used as an example, how variable data can
% be managed in the header.
% Macro `\headdate{...}' defines the macro `\theheaddate'
% with the given date. `\theheaddate' is used later in
% the fancy headers.
\newcommand*{\headdate}[1]{%
  \def\theheaddate{#1}%
}
% The default for the date (\theheaddate) is "YYYY/MM" of the current date.
\headdate{\the\year/\ifnum\month<10 0\fi\the\month}

% The images contains `2010/11' as date.
% \headdate{2010/11}

% Defining the fancy page style:
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead{}
\fancyfoot{}
\renewcommand*{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand*{\footrulewidth}{0pt}

% The header as table. Because we are using the french `:', the shorthand
% must be activated, because we are still in the preamble. Package babel
% activates them at `\begin{document}'.
\shorthandon{:}
\newcommand*{\theheader}{% 
  \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}[b]{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}cc@{}}%
    \multicolumn{2}{r@{}}{\thepage}\\%
    \hline
    \mbox{}\\%
    UNIVERSITE MOHAMMED PREMIER
    & Ann\'ee Universitaire \theheaddate\\
   \textsc{Facult\`e des Sciences}
   & Fili\`eres SM\\
   \textsc{D\`epartement de Math\`ematiques}
   & Semestre S1\\
   \textsc{et Informatique}
   &\\
   \textsc{-Oujda-}
   & Responsable: M.FILALI\\
  \end{tabular*}%
}
\chead{\theheader}
% The shorthand is turned off to avoid trouble with the loading of
% other packages.
\shorthandoff{:}

% As the header table is much larger than the standard `\headheight`,   
% these calculations fixes the `\headheight` by moving space from
% the text body to the header.
\addtolength{\textheight}{\headheight}
\settoheight{\headheight}{\vbox{\hbox{\theheader}\kern0pt}}
% The `\vbox{...\kern0pt}' construction is a trick to simulate the
% missing `\settototalheight'.
\addtolength{\textheight}{-\headheight}

% For debugging, option `showframe' shows the page layout
% and option `pass' tells `geometry' not to change the layout, but
% to use the current values.
\usepackage[pass,showframe]{geometry}

\begin{document}
\section{Hello World}
Start of line\hfill end of line.
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

**Remarks:**

- I have not moved the right block into the right margin as in the image. I think, it looks better, if the right block is aligned with the page number.

Comment: oh wow O_o , a really great result you have there, honestly i didn't understand all the code, i never used that kind of commands before, just the basic ones (\rhead; \lhead and so), even with the comments inside the file it's quite difficult to follow :( but thank you very much for your help i'll try to comprehend all this stuff